# JavaScript API - Query and Edit point from Feature Layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, select

I am attempting to recreate the ESRI example for attribute inspections (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_attribute_inspector.html).

I am having an issue when I create my feature service that contains a point feature class vs. the polygon feature class the example uses.

My initSelectToolbar(evt) function isn't "seeing" the point from the feature layer. If I only change the urls to the feature/map services (noted in commented out service declaration) the selection works successfully.

Am I missing something obvious here? Why can I not grab the point?

> Blockquote

```
            var map;
            var updateFeature;
            var map, geocoder, currentBaseMap;
            var locatorUrl = "http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/SDE.AddressLocator_Comp/GeocodeServer";

            require([
              "esri/map",
              "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
              "esri/dijit/AttributeInspector",
              "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
              "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
              "dojo/_base/Color",
              "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
              "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
              "esri/config",
              "esri/tasks/query",
              "dojo/parser",
              "dojo/dom-construct",
              "dijit/form/Button",
              "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function (
              Map, FeatureLayer, AttributeInspector,
              SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, Color,
              ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, esriConfig,
              Query,
              parser, domConstruct, Button
            ) {
                parser.parse();
                // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
                esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy";

                // Create the map
                map = new Map("mapDiv")
                map.on("layers-add-result", initSelectToolbar);
                //aerialsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/Aerials_4inch_12inch_Cached/MapServer", { "id": "Aerials", "visible": false });
                //map.addLayer(aerialsLayer);
                streetsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://gisaprd/ArcGIS/rest/services/SRSLandbase/MapServer", { "id": "Streets" });
                map.addLayer(streetsLayer);
                currentBaseMap = "Streets";

                var ISS_Inspections = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://gisadev:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ISS_Inspections/MapServer", { "id": "ISS_Inspections" });
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // If I use a map service with only polygons this works
                //var ISS_Inspections = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://gisadev:6080/arcgis/rest/services/testDeleteMe2222/MapServer", { "id": "ISS_Inspections" });

                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ISS_Inspections.setDisableClientCaching(true);
                map.addLayer(ISS_Inspections);

                var ISS_InspectionsFL = new FeatureLayer("http://gisadev:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ISS_Inspections/FeatureServer/0", {
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // If I use a feature service with only polygons this works
                    //    var ISS_InspectionsFL = new FeatureLayer("http://gisadev:6080/arcgis/rest/services/testDeleteMe2222/FeatureServer/0", {
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
                        outFields: ["*"] 
                        });
                highlightSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 255, 0]));
                ISS_InspectionsFL.setSelectionSymbol(highlightSymbol);
                ISS_InspectionsFL.on("edits-complete", function () {
                    ISS_Inspections.refresh();
                });
                map.addLayers([ISS_InspectionsFL]);


                function initSelectToolbar(evt) {
                    var ISS_InspectionsFL = evt.layers[0].layer;
                    var selectQuery = new Query();

                    map.on("click", function (evt) {
                        selectQuery.geometry = evt.mapPoint;

                        ISS_InspectionsFL.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {
                            if (features.length > 0) {
                                //store the current feature
                                updateFeature = features[0];
                                map.infoWindow.setTitle(features[0].getLayer().name);
                                map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
                            } else {
                                map.infoWindow.hide();
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    map.infoWindow.on("hide", function () {
                        ISS_InspectionsFL.clearSelection();
                    });

                    var layerInfos = [{
                        'featureLayer': ISS_InspectionsFL,
                        'showAttachments': false,
                        'isEditable': true,
                        'fieldInfos': [
                          { 'fieldName': 'PS_READING_INLET_SIDE', 'isEditable': true, 'tooltip': 'Current Status', 'label': 'Status:' },
                        ]
                    }];

                    var attInspector = new AttributeInspector({
                        layerInfos: layerInfos
                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));

                    //add a save button next to the delete button
                    var saveButton = new Button({ label: "Save", "class": "saveButton" });
                    domConstruct.place(saveButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode, "after");

                    saveButton.on("click", function () {
                        updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, [updateFeature], null);
                    });

                    attInspector.on("attribute-change", function (evt) {
                        //store the updates to apply when the save button is clicked 
                        updateFeature.attributes[evt.fieldName] = evt.fieldValue;
                    });

                    attInspector.on("next", function (evt) {
                        updateFeature = evt.feature;
                        console.log("Next " + updateFeature.attributes.objectid);
                    });

                    attInspector.on("delete", function (evt) {
                        evt.feature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, null, [feature]);
                        map.infoWindow.hide();
                    });

                    map.infoWindow.setContent(attInspector.domNode);
                    map.infoWindow.resize(350, 240);
                }
            }
            );
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the problem that 'evt.layers[0].layer' doesn't resolve within the edit initialization function or that you just can't trigger the query when clicking on the map?

if the second, check out this blog post/sample code on querying points and polylines by clicking the map.

Querying points and lines on click with the ArcGIS JavaScript API
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/01/15/querying-points-and-lines-on-click-with-the-arcgis-javascript-api/

Comment: I think the issue is related to the blog post/sample link you provided. Thanks.